# Rendering Postscript data to HDC

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi, postscript

I am working on a win32 application. In this application I want to display postscript data on the window DC.

Please, can anyone suggest how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostScript is an interpreted programming language, so you can't 'display PostScript data'. You need to execute the program by using a PostScript interpreter.

Which PostScript interpreter you use is up to you, it will depend on whether you are prepared to pay for a commercial interpreter, or can abide by the GPL open source licence.

If you are happy to use GPL software, then I suggest Ghostscript, the simple application for Windows even uses win32 API calls to do pretty much what I think you want, so you can use it as a working example.

Comment: Thanks for your input. where can i download the dll and Win32 sample.

Comment: All the Ghostscript sources can be found at the ghostscript site www.ghostscript.com